# How can i pass data from UIViewController to SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, swrevealviewcontroller

i wanna pass data (login/pass) from the AuthentificationController to the HomeController which is related to an SWRevealViewController with custom segue 'sw_front'
there is no relation between the AuthentificationController and HomeController
how should i do to pass data ?

how can i send data to the HomeController using the SWRevealViewController

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let secondView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "swreveal") as! SWRevealViewController
// passing the data here
   self.present(secondView, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please refer to [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You could pass data to SWRevealViewController and then to HomeController.

Comment: SWRevealViewController do not have a swift class he have .h and .m classes :/

Comment: SWRevealViewController is a class that you created or is it from certain library?